# Android Studio create vector asset with only outside the image transparent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm not asking how to create a normal transparent vector asset (in which we only need to set the background property to transparent), but how to create a vector asset that within the "image", it covers up all the things, but outside it's transparent, to better illustrate here's an example.

[image]

at the right bottom corner there is a ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24 asset, I want to make the area in four of its corners transparent, so that they won't cover up the person placeholder image behind it (but keeping the area within the circle remains solid).

Comment: Make it transparent and fill the circle with white?

Comment: could you post an answer with code? I'm still rather new to Android development

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 path and set the fillAlpha=0 like this example:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="200">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeWidth="3"
        android:pathData="M15,15 A80,45 0 0,1 80,50 M80,50 A100,45 0 0,1 15,85 A5,15 0 1,0 15,15 M15,15z M0,30 L25,30z M0,70 L25,70z" />
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeWidth="3"
        android:pathData="M8,17 A5,15 0 0,1 8,83 M15,15z M81,50 A3,3 0 1,1 90,50 M81,50 A3,3 0 0,0 90,50 M90,50 L100,50z" />
</vector>
```